# How to render only a part of EBO in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have VAO with bound VBO and EBO. Previously I've just been rendering it with `glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, EBO_size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 )`. But now I wanna draw it in parts, changing some uniforms in-between. Aka if I have 36 indices in EBO; I might wanna draw 18, change the uniform, and draw the remaining 18.

I tried `glDrawRangeElements`, but its `start` and `end` parameters are just hints for which indices will be used. `glDrawArrays` ignores the EBO and draws from the VBO directly.

Comment: Last parameter in the `glDrawElements` function is an offset into your EBO. If you pass `0` than it starts from the beginning. If you pass `i * sizeof(uint32_t)` than it starts from `i`th index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glDrawElements` `void* indices` parameter is actually a starting offset in bytes. And as you know, `GLsizei count` is the amount of elements to draw (not in bytes!)

For example, this would draw an EBO of 36 indices in two parts:

```
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 18, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(0) )
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 18, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(18*sizeof(unsigned int)) )
```